# How to visualize BPTT gradients in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'd like to view the gradients of my Tensorflow LSTM over time, for example, by plotting the norm of the gradient from t=N through t=0. The question is, how can I get the gradient per timestep out of Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

In the graph define:

```
params = tf.trainable_variables()
opt = get_optimizer(optimizer)(self.learning_rate)
gradients = tf.gradients(self.losses, params)
self.gradient_norm = tf.global_norm(gradients)
self.updates = opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, params), global_step=self.global_step)
```

Then eval self.gradient_norm or feed it to a SummariesWriter

Comment: Will that give the gradients per timestep, or the sum of gradients over all timesteps?

Comment: Sorry, per timestep... Didn'T realize. Wouldn't know. I would know how to plot loss per timestep though. That helps?

Comment: The losses variable could be just "mse" or would it need to be more than one loss?